# Playback an audio file to a specific channel in asterisk dialplan

Tags: asterisk

I need to make a voice translation service on active calls like skype, for that purpose I need to record voice from caller and whisper the translated voice to callee and vise-versa

I need to add to the dialplan lines to playback audio to the other channel with lower voice but current playback app doesn't have this option

any solution for that?
this is my code below

```
[macro-speech]
;;Speech recognition demo:
;exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,1,agi(googletts.agi,"Say something in English, when done press the pound key.",en)
exten => s,n(record),agi(speech-recog.agi,en-us)
exten => s,n,Verbose(1,Script returned: ${confidence} , ${utterance},en-us)

;Check the probability of a successful recognition:
exten => s,n(success),GotoIf($["${confidence}" > "0.6"]?playback:retry)

;Playback the text:

exten => s,n(playback),agi(googletts.agi,"The text you just said was...",en)
exten => s,n,agi(googletts.agi,"${utterance}",en)

;------------- Translate to different languages
;Translate a text string from english to german:
exten => s,n,agi(googletranslate.agi,"${utterance}",de)
exten => s,n,agi(googletts.agi,"${gtranslation}",de)
;------------------------------------------------
exten => s,n,goto(record)
;Retry in case speech recognition wasn't successful:
exten => s,n(retry),agi(googletts.agi,"Can you please repeat more clearly?",en)
exten => s,n,goto(record)

exten => s,n(fail),agi(googletts.agi,"Failed to get speech data.",en)
exten => s,n(end),Hangup()
```

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried?

Comment: I have attached the code in the question

Answer (score -1):

```
freepbx11*CLI> core show function VOLUME 

  -= Info about function 'VOLUME' =- 

[Synopsis]
Set the TX or RX volume of a channel. 

[Description]
The VOLUME function can be used to increase or decrease the 'tx' or 'rx' gain
of any channel.
For example:
Set(VOLUME(TX)=3)
Set(VOLUME(RX)=2)
Set(VOLUME(TX,p)=3)
Set(VOLUME(RX,p)=3)

[Syntax]
VOLUME(direction[,options])

[Arguments]
direction
    Must be 'TX' or 'RX'.
options
    p: Enable DTMF volume control


[See Also]
Not available
freepbx11*CLI>
```

Comment: what about playback on single leg of the call?

Comment: chanspy works in a new channel, not optimal for the task

Comment: For your task will be new channel anyway. Or you have do c/c++ coding, and THAT is not optimal.

Comment: Ok, would you please give me an example of how to use chanspy in my code